# Get/save image with Php curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

We are saving images to the database with PHP curl. We take the addresses of images from xml. After recording the image, we are experiencing the following problem. The images are superimposed, they are recorded incorrectly. Or the images are saved as a blank image with the name.

```
function resim($link, $klasor, $dosya)
{
    if (!file_exists($klasor)) {
        mkdir($klasor);
    }

    $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($link,"."),1));
    if ($type == 'jpeg') {
        $type = 'jpg';
    }

    $resim = fopen("{$klasor}/{$dosya}.{$type}", 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $resim );
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($resim);
}
```

- Where are we making mistakes? Or can we do it in another way?
- How do we get the image completion information?

Our respect.

Answer (score 0):

this depends upon the API that handles the upload function. you might be passing a wrong image format to the API. For example it might be accepting base64 content of the image

Comment: Thanks Alaa Attia Mohamed. We will put restrictions on the file format. Best Regards.